# Mailchimp alternative which allows duplicate or empty email addresses

Tags: web-apps, email, mailing-list

I am creating a list of addresses from people who've sent an email, called or filled in our online form. 
Due to the fact that not everyone who calls has an email address, I am looking for an alternative solution to Mailchimp to store my list.

There are also some people who send an email for themselves and their relatives. So an option to allow duplicate email addresses would also be nice to have.

I am currently using the free plan in Mailchimp to manage 3 lists with a total of 150 subscribers. 
Is there a service available with low price, a free plan or even special offers for non-profit organisations which would allow me to:

- Send personal emails to subscribers(with unsubscribe option)
- The option to creating a form to subscribe
- Insert rows without an email address
- Optional: Allows the insertion of duplicate emails

Comment: I'm not sure this qualifies as a [software recommendation request as per this site's standards](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), given that MailChimp is a service company.

Comment: This question from my understanding should be on-topic as it can be considered a [web-app](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/219/133). You should, however, provide us with more information of what you're asking specifically highlighting needed features and what your budget is.

Comment: Even the remark *resembles in price* is unclear because you don't say what plan you are on. Also: how would you enter the sync the service's list with the mutations in the email addresses? Please [edit] all additional info into your question text.